# Returning last inserted id in C# using Repository

Tags: c#, .net-core, aspnetboilerplate

In a `.NET Core`/`C#` application, using the `Boilerplate framework` I use repositories for data access:

`await _licenseRepository.InsertAsync(license);`

But in a method I need to do two inserts in two different tables, and then do the relationship:

```
public async Task Insert(License license, LicenseRenewal licenseRenewal)
{
    var l = await _licenseRepository.InsertAsync(license);
    var lr = await _licenseRenewalRepository.InsertAsync(licenseRenewal);
    await AssignRenewal(l.Id, lr.Id);
}
```

The problem is that when I do the Insert I do not get the IDs of the new data and so it fails to do the `AssignRenewal`.

**How do I get the ID of the inserted data?**

Comment: can you please add code for `InsertAsync`?

Comment: Did you try `license.Id` and `licenseRenewal.Id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Repositories#insert](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Repositories#insert) states:

> "[...] The InsertAndGetId method returns the Id of a newly inserted
> entity.[...]"

So you should try

```
Task<TPrimaryKey> InsertAndGetIdAsync(TEntity entity);
```